# Mouse focus and keyboard error in windows

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, mouse, window-management

My mouse is still able to move my cursor, but it is unable to interact with the windows under certain conditions. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work, but I can use my desktop with my keyboard with some success.

I want to report this bug, but I don't know under which package to file it in launchpad. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when plugging in my Cyborg RAT 7 mouse. To fix this (at least for my mouse, maybe yours too), add this to /etc/X11/xorg.conf (create the file if it's not there):

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Mouse Remap"
    MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.7 Mouse"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 9 10 11 12 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Log out and log back in and your mouse should work fine. Change the MatchProduct line and ButtonMapping (if necessary) to match your mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  I just upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10.  When I log in, one of the following happens:

1. I can't click anything.  I have to ALT+CTRL+DEL, then log out.
2. My mouse works fine, until I use it to launch something.  For instance, if I launch my browser or terminal, I can no longer use the mouse*.

*Sometimes I can click the bar at the top of the window (i.e. I can click the task bar area near the time, or minimize the window).

My keyboard still works.  I can still press the Start button on my keyboard and open the dash, and type.  I just can't click properly!  Is there anything like xprop or xwininfo that can tell me what has stolen my mouse?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/41301 i think this is the launchpad bug

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been solved for me if of course i was suffering from it :) my symptoms where:

-mouse failing to get focus on various windows
-keyboad alt-tab also not responding
-unity keeps focus
-and other kinds of weird behaviour of the mouse

How? Regular ubuntu update on 09-05-2012.

Thank you Ubuntu

*edit: bug is still there